# <?php if function, search for a string that contains data

Tags: php

Hope all is well.

I'm wanting to display a series of badges which would display different images based on a field which contains a specific string. For example, something like this (although I'm aware that this is probably not correct)

```
            <?php if (stripos($business, "local") !== false) 
echo "badge-icon1.png"; ?>
        <?php if (stripos($business, "interstate") !== false) 
echo "badge-icon2.png"; ?>
        <?php if (stripos($business, "national") !== false) 
echo "badge-icon3.png"; ?>
        <?php if (stripos($business, "international") !== false) 
echo "badge-icon4.png"; ?>
```

I'm familiar with the stripos function, although I'm not sure whether or not it is suitable for an array of alternative scenarios based on if one field contains one of a few string options.

Is there an alternative method which may be a little more suitable?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Is the *entire* string the word `local` or `interstate` or...?

Comment: Maybe `switch(strtolower($business))` if it is a complete match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripos` isn't really suitable here as it will match `national` in both `national` and `international`. If the entire `$business` string is the word `local` or `interstate` etc. you might find an array easier to work with:

```
$badges = array('local' => 'badge-icon1.png',
                'interstate' => 'badge-icon2.png',
                'national' => 'badge-icon3.png',
                'international' => 'badge-icon2.png'
                );
echo $badges[$business] ?? '';
```

If `$business` might have uppercase characters in it (e.g. `Local`), use `strtolower($business)` as the array index:

```
echo $badges[strtolower($business)] ?? '';
```

Also, if you want to have a default image for when `$business` doesn't match one of the 4 names, you can put that in the `echo`:

```
echo $badges[$business] ?? 'badge-placeholder.png';
```

Comment: i'd do it this way too, and use the else ternary with a `badge-placeholder.png` of some sort instead of an empty string, that way i'd still get a default